# Op-amp based audio amplifier not working

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have a problem with audio amplifier I am trying to build. Given my ignorance, I cannot figure out how to fix the issue. There is absolutely no sound on the output. This is what I have assembled:

[image: Schematic]

*EDIT1*

Kaz, Venny,

Perhaps I misunderstood something you said, but trying my best I modified the circuit into this form:

[image]

And sadly it is not working yet. I would like to apologize for my utter nescience of the topic.

Comment: niF should be nF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a serious input and output voltage range problem : the input signal must stay within input voltage range (V- to V+ -2V) and the expected output voltage must stay within output voltage range (V- to V+ - 3.5V). Here is what I suggest :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBT42e.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This way :

- The input voltage swings around ground, and stays far from the power rails.
- The output can swing from -9V to about +5V

As Kaz noted, the output drive of LM358 is probably not strong enough for headphones ; you may want to add an output booster stage between the LM358 out and the pot.

If you want to stay with single battery, you will need to create a ground at an intermediate value (I'd suggest around 3V since that op-amp output swing is limited from V- to about 3.5V below V+). For that you can replace the two batteries with a single and create the ground from a resistive divider and an op-amp (the second half of your lm358) as buffer :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwzQik.png)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much. I copied your two battery version and it is working nicely now. Also thank you Kaz and Venny. I would like to again apologize for my utter ignorance in the topic. To me it is, I think, like differentiating for someone who can barely add. I read some tutorials etc. but it is still highly confusing to me. I will keep on learning. Thank you again.    Also one more question if I may. When I keep turning up potentiometer to get higher gains at some point it basically stop working. As you already suggested I should get more suitable op amp for that, yes?

Comment: There are many ways in which this circuit can be improved, but first you needed to realy understand how the basic version works. As for why it stops working at high volume, it is probably because the op amp output can not drive enough current for your headphones : with a typical headphone impedance around ten Ohm, the current would be hundreds of mA. To increase the output to such a level you need to add a booster stage between your op-amp output and the pot. This can be done cheapest with two transistors, a npn and a pnp (google "push-pull op amp output booster" for examples).

Answer (score 5):

The most obvious problem in the circuit is that the + input of the amplifier is floating; it is not biased to any DC voltage level. You need to convey a reference voltage to this input. (This has to be done through a reasonably large resistor; if you just tie the input to a stiff reference voltage, the input will have no impedance to work against.)

Additional problems stem from the choice of part for the circuit. Firstly, although the LM358 can run on as little as 3V, you neglected to look at the common mode input range: according to the [data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm158-n.pdf) that range is from \$0\$ to \$V^+ - 2\$ or \$0\$ to \$V^+ - 1.5\$: depending of which of two conflicting tables you believe. This means that on such a low supply voltage, you are better of building an inverting amplifier which keeps the common mode input voltages fixed. If you stick to the \$0\$ to \$V^+ - 2\$ recommendation, this means you would build the inverting stage such that it is biased to 1V.

Next, look at the terrible output voltage swing figures! On nice, big 30V supply, the op-amp will only swing up to 26V: a bad sign: the op-amp struggles to come within 4V of the upper power rail. No VOH (high output voltage swing) figures are given for any lower voltage, but for 3V, it will probably be next to nonexistent.

So the fact that the op-amp can "work" on 3V does not mean much: it has poor output voltage swing, and a crummy common mode input range.  If you need an op-amp that works meaningfully on 3V, you need something more modern: something with rail-to-rail output (if not input, too).

Lastly, the LM358 is not very suitable for driving headphones (even when adequately juiced); that application requires an amplifier with an output stage that has decent current driving ability: a power amplifier. (Among the operational amplifiers, one example of a part that is acceptable for driving headphones is the the [NJM4556](http://www.njr.com/semicon/products/NJM4556A.html); however it is not low power, and will not run on 3V.)

Comment: The 5 to 20 mV is for V_OL, but yes, the output swing would be almost nonexistent.

Comment: @venny My bad. That table layout is slightly confusing. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have no path for bias current. Add 1Mohm resistor from +3V to in+. Also the ring of audio input must be referenced to half of supply voltage, so add voltage divider consisting of two 10k resistors between +3V and 0V with the centre connected to ground (the grey line).

Comment: That resistor divider should have the middle tied to + input, not ground! Also I would go for larger resistors so that they cancel input bias current, say 220k each.